# Sample code for Uploading video on YouTube

Tags: ios, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, google-data-api

I am looking for a working sample code that can upload video to YouTube on iOS (Objective-C or Swift). From what I have understood in the new flow, I need:

1. Authenticate using GTMAppAuth or [Google Sign-In SDK](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/)
2. Use GTLRYouTubeService class to manage upload

There may still be missing links. I don't see a single working code that runs on iOS. Can anyone point me in the right direction?